# Help identifying a part of a flower

Tags: botany, homework, plant-physiology, flowers, morphology

I researched about floral diagrams and this is what I found:-
This is floral diagram of ***Theobroma cacao***. I managed to identify others but this part near the **stamens** was not found anywhere.
Also the floral diagram includes some **circular parts** which I have highlighted.

So what exactly are these parts called?[image: w]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floral_diagram

Comment: Please could you include a link to the source of your image. Thanks.

Comment: Because the background is now black rather than the white in the original diagram you've lost essential information. It also looks to me like a careful reading of the linked wikipedia page answers your questions. One hint that may help you is to think about how the cross-section of a stamen changes along its length. That will help you recognize structures you've circled in green. ——— Please also read the ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) guidelines. (Note that "homework" can apply to questions even if they are not assigned as homework.)

Comment: ok i have corrected but I couldn't find any information about these pars